# sqlite_config on os x

Tags: sql, database, macos, sqlite

I run this code in OS X:

```
NSLog(@"sqlite3_threadsafe %d", sqlite3_threadsafe());
NSLog(@"sqlite3_config return %d", sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED));
NSLog(@"sqlite3_threadsafe %d", sqlite3_threadsafe());
NSLog(@"sqlite3_libversion %s", sqlite3_libversion());
```

I get this:

```
2013-09-10 11:49:51.177 SqliteTest[32864:303] sqlite3_threadsafe 2
2013-09-10 11:49:51.179 SqliteTest[32864:303] sqlite3_config return 0
2013-09-10 11:49:51.180 SqliteTest[32864:303] sqlite3_threadsafe 2
2013-09-10 11:49:51.180 SqliteTest[32864:303] sqlite3_libversion 3.7.12
```

The second sqlite3_threadsafe() should return 3.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/threadsafe.html) says:

> The return value of the sqlite3_threadsafe() function shows only the compile-time setting of thread safety, not any run-time changes to that setting made by sqlite3_config(). In other words, the return value from sqlite3_threadsafe() is unchanged by calls to sqlite3_config().